# Reading Credit Card info using PointOfService API in UWP

Tags: uwp, credit-card, pointofservice

Has anyone had any success with the PointOfService.MagneticStripeReader objects?  The sample from Microsoft UWP Examples (Git) does not even work with my card reader (iDTech IDRE-335133B) which is on the supported devices list for UWP.

I can get access to the device and claim it, but the events NEVER fire when I scan a valid card.  The reader evens beeps twice (which means it has read and decrypted 2 data tracks successfully) but the events NEVER fire.

If anyone knows the trick to get this please let me know.

Chuck

Comment: still nothing....hmmm...

Answer (score 1):

This is related to a known issue that where the IDTech SecureMag configured as Security Level 1 (non-encrypting) does not fire a data event whereas the same IDTech SecureMag configured as Security Level 3 (encrypting) does work just fine.

It was fixed on 6/22 and is currently available through the Windows Insider builds (build 16237 or later).